# context menu event both opens default context menu and fires the event

Tags: angular

I am trying to open mat-menu, when right clicking on an object.
my code is:

```
<div class="component-div" fxLayout="column" fXLayoutAlign="center space-between" (contextmenu)="onRightClick($event)">        
  <div class="header-title">
      <button mat-button class="xs-btn" (click)="addObject()">Add Object</button>
      <button mat-button class="xs-btn" (click)="addBranch()">Add Branch</button>
      <button mat-button class="xs-btn" (click)="addLabel()">Add Label</button>
      <button mat-button class="xs-btn" (click)="addText()">Add Text</button>
   </div>

<div class="content-div" #graphContainer id="graphContainer" (contextmenu)="onRightClick($event)">
      <button mat-button [matMenuTriggerFor]="menu" id="menuBtn" style="display:none;"></button>
      <mat-menu #menu="matMenu" (close)="onMenuClosed()">
          <button class="menuOpnBtn" mat-menu-item *ngFor="let opn of addTextToOpns" (click)="editCell(opn)">
              {{ opn }}
          </button>
      </mat-menu>
</div>
</div>
```

it looks like this:
The mat-menu opens fine, but also the default menu:
[image]

I will appreciate any help.

Another issue I have: how do I know to which item the menu refers to?

Tx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found it!
All is needed to do is add :

```
event.preventDefault();
```

in the onRightClick(event:any) method.

Answer (score 0):

[Mat-menu is a floating panel containing list of options](https://material.angular.io/components/menu/overview). To open mat-menu, right click is not the option. Since it's a simple dropdown you can only left-click.

If you use [Context menu](https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/contextmenu) you can achieve what you need

> https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/contextmenu